# Problem from Mathematical Analysis by Bernd Schroder

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Here's the problem I'm doing.

Let $f: (a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and let $x \in (a,b)$. Prove that if $f'(z)$ exists for all $z \in (a,b) \setminus \{x\}$ and $\lim_{z \to x} f'(z)$ exists, then $f$ is differentiable at $x$ with $f'(x) = \lim_{z \to x} f'(z) = f'(x)$.

---

Proof Attempt:

Let $\lim_{z \to x} f'(z) = L$. Let $z > x$. Then, by Lagrange's Theorem:

$$\exists c \in (x,z): f'(c) = \frac{f(z)-f(x)}{z-x}$$

where $c$ will depend on $z$. So, we have:

$$D^r f(x) = \lim_{z \to x^+} \frac{f(z)-f(x)}{z-x} = \lim_{z \to x^+} f'(c) = L$$

where $D^r f(x)$ is the right-sided derivative at $x$. Let $z < x$. Then, by Lagrange's Theorem:

$$\exists c \in (z,x): f'(c) = \frac{f(x)-f(z)}{x-z} = \frac{f(z)-f(x)}{z-x}$$

where $c$ will depend on $z$. So, we have:

$$D^l f(x) = \lim_{z \to x^-} \frac{f(z)-f(x)}{z-x} = \lim_{z \to x^-} f'(c) = L$$

where $D^l f(x)$ is the left-sided derivative of $f$ at $x$. Since both the left and right derivatives exist and are equal, $f'(x)$ exists and we conclude that $f'(x) = L$. $\Box$

Does the proof above work? If it doesn't, then why? How can I fix it?

Comment: Fine. You could make it shorter by saying "Let $x\ne z\in (a,b).$ Then there exists $c$ between $x$ and $z$ such that ...", so as to handle the LH and RH cases together.

Comment: Ahh I see, that makes sense too. Thank you so much for the feedback :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially fine.  Normally you might state that your functions meets the requirements of Lagrange's theorem and also then make explicit that as $z \to x$, the corresponding $c \to x$ so that as $z \to x$, $f'(c) \to L$ and therefore $\frac{f(z)-f(x)}{z-x} \to L$.

Comment: Yeap, that makes sense. Thank you very much!